# MNAR Imputation On Time Series Data in Ongoing Study

Tags: panel-data, missing-data, data-imputation, expectation-maximization, mnar

I am working on an ongoing study that tracks subjects through time. Each subject is enrolled for months, where upon exiting I calculate their length-of-stay.

Since the study is ongoing, I have both active (still enrolled) and inactive subjects (no longer required to participate). Without the terminal endpoint, I can't calculate their length-of-stay. If I run summary statistics on length-of-stay, the dates closer to present day will be biased towards shorter length-of-stays: only the subjects that have entered and left the study will have a terminal point.

Furthermore, substitution imputation methods are inaccurate: the substitution methods will also bias for shorter length-of-stays. We know that the active cases have, at minimum, a length-of-stay that is greater than today's date, subtracted by their enrollment date.

Does anyone have a recommended method for MNAR that also allows for the constraint listed above?